# how to load AngularJS code in bootstrap modal using asp.net core mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I want to use AngularJS code inside bootstrap modal i am loading the bootstrap modal with Jquery code
and after loading the modal i want to use angular JS code to fetch and insert data.The angular code is working fine in seperate view but when i tried to use it in modal i am getting angular js warning of
**Tried to load angular more than once in bootstrap modal**.How can i successfully get this working.

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.className').on('click', function () {
            $.get('url', { id: id, mid: mid }, function (data) {
                $('#detail').html(data);
                $('#modal').modal('show');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In Bootstrap modal i have following code

```
 @model Model
    
            <div class="modal-lg modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content panel panel-info">
                    <div class="modal-header panel-heading">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-app="MyApp">
                        <div ng-controller="MyController">
                            <div class="modal-body panel-body">
                                <table id="tblCustomers" class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                   //TO Show Data
                                </table>
    
     
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    //Form to insert data
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])

    app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
        $scope.btntext = "Save";
      
        $scope.Savedata = function () {
           //For Saving
        }

        $http.get("url").then(function (data) {
           //For fetching data
        });
</script>
```

The html control through which i am loading the modal is inside another partial view
so i have main view inside that one partial view and from that i am loading the modal which is also a partial view.

Can anybody help me

Comment: Does this warning affect the data display or any function achieve? Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether there has some error in the Console panel. Besides, I also try to create a view page in my .net core MVC application and put the Bootstrap Modal in the partial view and put the JavaScript and CSS reference and my custom JavaScript script on the main page, then everything works well. So, I suggest you can post the Enough code (include the main page and partial view code) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think the error code tells you that you already have angular loaded - thus you can use it inside modal without load it again
I guess you have reference to angular library in more than one place

Comment: but after adding angular code inside modal it is not giving me the expected result

Comment: as far as i understand the only unexpected thing you can see- is "more than once" warning, am i right?